# Shrink sleeve label on bottle product

Tags: uv, shrinkwrap

I am new to the blender and creating a fitness-type product (Below is the sample image). Now, I am facing issues wrapping the label around the product like the given image. Is there anybody who can guide me on how to do this type of wrapping or is there any video available on it?
Thank You
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The label should be part of the material of your bottle. So first unwrap your faces with the *Cylinder Projection* option:

[image]

In the *UV Editor* put the UV island correctly over the image:

[image]

Create a material with an *Image Texture* node (with your image) plugged into the *Base Color* input of the *Principled BSDF*, assign this material to the faces:

[image]